# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to run web application on Apache tomcat and My sql . Earlier it was running on oracle 11g and wildfly and it is working fine , Please find below attached xml configuration files . Thanks in advance.

**this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
  
       <bean id="myBeansValidator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/> 
       <mvc:annotation-driven validator="myBeansValidator"/> 
  
  
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.ars"/>
  
       <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <!--  <property name="viewClass">
             <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
         </property> --> 
         <property name="prefix">
                <value>/</value>
         </property>
       </bean> 
  
   <!-- <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.cg"/> -->
 
  <!-- This bean is required to load ORM persistence and related annotations -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
  
 <!-- This bean will hold references to our database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080" />
     <property name="username" value="root" />
     <property name="password" value="root" />
     </bean> 
 
 <!-- Spring way of entity manager factory configuration -->
 
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spring.ars"/>
            <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
            <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
               <map>
                  <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
                   <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
                   <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> 
              </map>
             </property>
        </bean> 
      
 <!-- This bean will handle all transaction within an application -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>
 
 <!-- This is required to handle transactions via Annotations like @Transactional -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
   
</beans>
```

**this is my web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AirlineReservationSystem</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
    
   <jsp-config>
     <jsp-property-group>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
     </jsp-property-group>
   </jsp-config>
    
   <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
 
    <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
  
</web-app>
```

**Stack trace**

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
>       ... 32 more

Comment: Show your `pom.xml` or your lib list.

Comment: check the datasource properties. The mysql port is 8080.  what is your http port? also ensure the mysql jar is in classpath.

Comment: Exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] `. So add mysql connector jar to `WEB-INF/lib` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

If you are using a mysql
change your hibernate property

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spring.ars"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that you don't have the MySQL driver in your classpath:

Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

Please make sure that in your apps WEB-INF/lib folder or in the tomcat lib folder you have the proper MySQL connector/driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

If you don't have it either manually add it, or if you are using maven with your project you can add it to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```